# Rails Devise login using curl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, devise, authenticity-token

I'm trying to login to devise using `curl` as follows:

```
curl -v -b cookie.file -c cookie.file -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"user" : {"email":"MYUSER" , "password":"MYPASSWORD" }}' <code>http://localhost:3000/users/sign_in.json<code>
```

The rails server logs shows:

```
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

Is it possible to get CSRF token authenticity and pass it to the sign_in request to login successfully using devise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you not to use `curl` and use `mechanize` instead because it handels this stuff automaticly when you call the login form first.

When you want to go on using curl you need to call the login page first and enable the `cookiejar` option to store the session for the next call. Then you could add the token so you can login. But this problem isnt specific to devise its a mecanism of Rails to not accept forms that were sent without the token.